# Struggling putting together an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, smf

I'm trying to further customize an existing modification for my site/forum, but unfortunately the author who I've asked for support has little spare time at the moment.

Can someone advise where I might be going wrong with this query?

```
            SELECT date FROM {db_prefix}log_activity
            WHERE date = 2015-12-25
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM {db_prefix}log_online 
            WHERE ID_MEMBER = $memberID );
```

I am basically looking to check if my specified date appears in {db_prefix}log_activity and if it does, trigger my action for all members found in {db_prefix}log_online

(more to the code but I think the above part is what causing me issues..)

Full code of my attempts:

```
            if (!in_array('test',$currentBadges))
            {

            $resultgroup = $smcFunc['db_query']('', "
            SELECT date FROM {db_prefix}log_activity
            WHERE date = 2015-04-20
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM {db_prefix}log_online 
            WHERE ID_MEMBER = $memberID );
            ");
            $totalRow = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($resultgroup);

            {
            $badgeAction = 'test';
            if (!in_array($badgeAction,$currentBadges) && $totalRow['total'] >= 1)
            {
            $badgeID = GetBadgeIDByAction($badgeAction);
            $ret = AddBadgeToMember($memberID,$badgeID,false);
            if ($ret == true)
            {
            $currentBadges[] = $badgeAction;
            $newBadges[]  = $badgeAction;
            }

            }


            }
            //end badge code
            }
```

I've never used this site before so hopefully that format's somewhat readable.. :P

Basically what I am attempting to do is:
IF (date) = today
AND (member) has logged in
THEN award badge...

Log of changed attempts:

```
            "WHERE date = 2015-04-20"
            WHERE date = "2015-04-20"
```

Comment: if you dont understand it your best to read on queries

Comment: this for one thing, needs to be quoted `WHERE date = 2015-12-25` otherwise MySQL figures you want to do math, as in substract, in turn spewing out a syntax error; something you're not checking for.

Comment: We'll certainly help you here, but I advise against asking people to do it for you - that's a sure way to get your question closed. I've edited this out.

Comment: I have very little knowledge and too much I want to learn!,

I find I receive worse errors when using quotes around the date / the whole line :(

Comment: Much appreciated and apologies, I'm not very familiar with this site!

Like I said, I have very little knowledge of PHP/SQL but seem to have been able to achieve everything I have looked into so far from reading/ using examples as templates / support etc.

Comment: if you've used quotes around the date, then modify your question with the way you have used it. What are you using to connect with, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? or PDO?

Comment: I have since removed the quotes again but I'll edit my question to show where I had them and mysql I believe.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you below to better illustrate.

Comment: "Much appreciated... I'm not very familiar with this site" - you're most welcome. FWIW, I'd say that the guidelines I outline are the case _everywhere on the web_, not just here. I've now upvoted, as the question looks quite good after the various edits.

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit in using `"WHERE date = 2015-04-20"`

You are using double quotes inside a double-quoted query.

Use single quotes like this and as per what you have in your originally posted code:

```
$resultgroup = $smcFunc['db_query']('', "
            SELECT date FROM {db_prefix}log_activity
            WHERE date = '2015-04-20'
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM {db_prefix}log_online 
            WHERE ID_MEMBER = $memberID );
            ");
```

Plus, if `$memberID` is not an integer, it would also need to be quoted.

I.e.:

```
$resultgroup = $smcFunc['db_query']('', "
            SELECT date FROM {db_prefix}log_activity
            WHERE date = '2015-04-20'
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM {db_prefix}log_online 
            WHERE ID_MEMBER = '$memberID' );
            ");
```

- But I somewhat doubt it. However, I needed to point that out just in case.

For more information on this, read the following on Stack

- [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

and string functions on the MySQL.com website:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Ahh, I now see where I was going wrong with the double / singles quotes.
Thank you for that! :P

Unfortunately my new code results in "Hacking Attempt..." but I presume this is SMF related to know why that is happening now?

Comment: @FourtwentyConnect that I won't be able to help with. Something else is causing that and I've no idea how, because I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I shall investigate the cause of that at the SMF support site.

- Many thanks for your help, I knew I wasn't too far off solving this one! - It's been bugging me for a while now!